# Solving two simultaneous equations in one complex variable

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I need some help / solutions for the following equations, where $M \ge 0 \in R$, $s \in C$, and $C_n$ are functions of $M$ only (stated further below)

Equation 1;

$$M+5\sqrt{M}+2=C_1s^{2\sqrt{M}+2}+C_2s^{2\sqrt{M}-2}+C_3s^2$$

Equation 2;

$$M-3\sqrt{M}+1=C_4s^{2\sqrt{M}+2}+C_5s^{\sqrt{M}+2}+C_6s^{\sqrt{M}}+C_7s^{\sqrt{M}+1}+C_8s^2$$

Where;

$$C_1 =\sqrt{M}-M$$
$$C_2 =(1+\sqrt{M})^2$$
$$C_3 =(1+\sqrt{M})$$
$$C_4 =(2-\sqrt{M})(\sqrt{M}-1)$$
$$C_5=C_6=C_8=(\sqrt{M}-1)^2$$
$$C_7 =-8\sqrt{M}$$

Comment: Mathematica can't solve this.

Comment: Ok, so what does that mean? - do solutions exist?

Comment: @lovsovs I have corrected the 2nd equation